# NPM/Node Error that I cannot resolve

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, libsodium, sodium

I am trying to install my packages for a bot (that work on another vps I own) using npm 5, ubuntu 16.04, and node.js 8. The issue seems to be with sodium/libsodium. Here is the error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/P05doix.png]

I've tried deleting all the node modules and reinstalling, nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `libtool`. The log is saying it doesn't find libsodium so it has to build it with `libtool` which it can't find on your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

While you add at it, make sure you have `automake` and `autoconf`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtool automake autoconf
```

Then try `npm install` again. Remove `node_modules` first to be safe.
Hope this is of help.